# Table refresh from Azure SQL database to on-premise SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, linked-server, transactional-replication, azure-data-sync

I have a similar requirement but the other way. I.e I have a table in an Azure SQL database, which we need to copy data from the Azure SQL database to an on-premise SQL Server database. The table refresh needs to be done once a day.

I am planning to create a linked server from the on-premise machine to Azure SQL, and then create a SQL Server Agent job to query the Azure SQL database from the on-premise server, download the data to `.csv` file, drop the existing table and re-create the table again and import the data from the `.csv` file.

Is this approach feasible? My table is very small and growth is very minimal. Please suggest if there is any easier way to do this task.

Comment: If you can create a linked server, you can just select and insert the data directly, no need for intermediate steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach you suggested is correct, but it can be lengthy one. instead of downloading data dropping table and again uploading data as @siggemannen suggested you cand directly insert the data with below script.

```sql
--THIS QUERY WILL TRUNCATE THE DATA FROM THE TABLE(DELETE ALL THE DATA FROM THE TABLE)
TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE_NAME;

-- tHIS WILL INSERT THE DATA FROM LINKED SERVER TABLE TO ON PREM TABLE.
INSERT INTO sampletable 
SELECT * FROM [LINKED_SERVSER_NAME].[DATABASE_NAME].[SCHEMA_NAME].[TABLE_NAME];
```

[image]

This will delete the records from table and insert the records from linked server table every time whenever SQL job will execute.

**SUCCESSFULL EXECUTION:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt response, This should work i will try and let you know.

Comment: It worked and thanks for the help!!!